# sort an array by inserting at the front or the end

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, queue

How would you sort an array of integers if you were only allowed to remove elements and place them either at the front or the back of the array? I think a simple way to think of this problem is in terms of a double ended queue, but I'm not really sure what would be the most efficient algorithm.

If I were to choose the largest element, place it at the front, then choose the second largest element, place it at the front, repeat... the time complexity would be O(n^2). What is a better approach to this problem?

You don't necessarily need to use an array, it could be an arrayList too (which sound better because inserting a the front or back wouldn't involve shifting everything.

Thank you! This isn't for homework, just plain curiosity!

Comment: IMHO, I don't think any solution better than O(N^2) exists for the allowed operations. If we could then it would become a new sorting algorithm.
If the given numbers are small, ~1e8, we can use modified counting sort to emulate the sorting

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can do a merge sort using only those operations.

Consider how merge sorting a linked list works. You create an empty linked list that is the destination. Then you compare the first two items in the source list and add them to the destination list in order (i.e. lowest first). You continue that for each pair of items in the list.

When you've finished comparing adjacent items, the destination list now becomes the source and you merge items 1,2,3,4, then items 5,6,7,8, etc.

You can do the same thing with just one linked list. If you know how many items are in the list (worst case, iterate over it and count them), then your output list is just the item after the last node in the list. So you compare the first two items and move them to the end of the list, in order. Repeat until the list is sorted.

Doing this with an array would of course be incredibly expensive because you'd continually be moving things up in order to make room at the end. But you could do it with an `ArrayList` (in Java) or `List<T>` (in C#) easily enough by just doubling the size of the list. You'd have to keep track of your destination index (`Count` for the first iteration, 0 for the next iteration, etc.), and you might have to move the final items to the front of the list when you're done (if you did an odd number of iterations). And, of course, you'd have to remove all of the extra items before returning. But it can be done.

Complexity is O(n log n) time and O(n) extra space if you're using an ArrayList. O(1) extra space if you're doing it with a linked list.

Comment: OP said, "If I were to choose the largest element, place it at the front, then choose the second largest element, place it at the front, repeat... the time complexity would be O(n^2). What is a better approach to this problem?"

Comment: @Fallen: thanks. I obviously didn't read the full question. Need coffee.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to go through every number multiple times.

If the previous number was smaller than current number and:

- the previous number was sent to the back, send it to the back.
- the previous number was sent to the front, leave it here
- the previous number remained, leave it here

If the previous number was larger than current number and:

- the previous number was sent to the back, leave it here
- the previous number was sent to the front, send it to the front.
- the previous number remained, send it to the front.

Now, im not sure about the time complexity...but its definately A WAY of doing it :)...anyways, it was fun thinking about it. I havn't thought about how to identify end conditions, but im sure that is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure under your restrictions am I able to do this:

1. Randomly pick an element(pivot) in the array, say its value's `x`
2. scan through the array other than the chosen element, move all elements which value <= x in front of the array, move all element which value > x at the end of the array
3. Recursively do the above for subarray (1,i-1) and (i+1, n) where the i-th element is the pivot

And yes, it is a well known algorithm named [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) which runs in `O(n lg n)` (avg case)

**Edited: After revise the question, I think the data structure for implementation is more important**

For data structure, I think a linked list is enough? Though it is not a good idea to use quicksort on a linked-list (You may want to implement merge sort instead, complexity still the same) as the constant would become much larger then normal quick sort on an array (due to random access become O(n) instead of O(1))